# OpenGL core profile incredible slowdown on OS X

Tags: macos, performance, opengl, profile

I added a new GL renderer to my engine, which uses the core profile. While it runs fine on Windows <strike>and/or nvidia cards</strike>, it is like 10 times slower on OS X (3 fps instead of 30). The weird thing is, that my compatibility profile renderer runs fine.

I collected some traces with Instruments and the GL profiler:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/311fg9wu0zrarzm/31CGvUcf2q

It shows that the application spends its time in glDrawRangeElements.
I tried the following things:

- use glDrawElements instead (no effect)
- flip culling (no effect on speed)
- disable some GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW buffers (no effect)
- bind index buffer after VAO when drawing (no effect)
- converted indices to 4 byte (no effect)
- use GL_BGRA textures (no effect)

What I didn't try is to align my vertices to 16 byte boundary <strike>and/or convert indices to 4 byte</strike>, but seriously, if that would be the issue then why the hell does the standard allow it?

I'm creating the context like this:

```
NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute attributes[] =
{
    NSOpenGLPFAColorSize, 24,
    NSOpenGLPFAAlphaSize, 8,
    NSOpenGLPFADepthSize, 24,
    NSOpenGLPFAStencilSize, 8,
    NSOpenGLPFADoubleBuffer,
    NSOpenGLPFAAccelerated,
    NSOpenGLPFANoRecovery,
    NSOpenGLPFAOpenGLProfile, NSOpenGLProfileVersion3_2Core,
    0
};

NSOpenGLPixelFormat* format = [[NSOpenGLPixelFormat alloc] initWithAttributes:attributes];
NSOpenGLContext* context = [[NSOpenGLContext alloc] initWithFormat:format shareContext:nil];

[self.view setOpenGLContext:context];
[context makeCurrentContext];
```

Tried on the following specs:

- radeon 6630M, OS X 10.7.5
- radeon 6750M, OS X 10.7.5
- geforce GT 330M, OS X 10.8.3

Do you have any ideas what I might do wrong? Again, it works fine with the compatibility profile (not using VAOs though).

**UPDATE**: reported to Apple.

**UPDATE**: Apple doesn't give a damn to the problem...anyway I created a small test program which is actually good. Now I compared the call stack with Instruments, and found out that when using the engine, *glDrawRangeElements* does two calls:

- gleDrawArraysOrElements_ExecCore
- gleDrawArraysOrElements_Entries_Body

while in the test program it calls only the second. Now the first call does something like an immediate mode render (gleFlushPrimitivesTCLFunc, gleRunVertexSubmitterImmediate), so obviously casues the slowdown.

Comment: "*but seriously, if that would be the issue then why the hell does the standard allow it?*" Because the standard doesn't define *performance*. Only functionality.

Comment: It almost sounds like it's falling back to software. You should profile it and see where the slowdown is. Also, can you run it with OpenGL Profiler and turn on all the error breakpoints? It may point out something you're missing (and will tell you if it's falling back to software).

Comment: I did enable error checking, as well as breaking on sw fallback, but nothing happened. Btw. the log I attached shows that the engine is also checking for GL errors every frame.

And as I mentioned the slowdown is clearly in glDrawRangeElements.

Comment: How large are the buffer data you are rendering?

Comment: Since GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT is enough it can't be large, and anyway it works fine with GL 2.

I tried much smaller or even larger models and all of them runs slow, regardless of shader or geometric complexity.

Comment: I'm completely shot...I wrote a test program which works. Copied everything from test program to engine, still slow. Thought that maybe I'm messing up something the way I create the window etc, so I did it good this time with interface builder and everything. Still slow... I really don't have any idea... I mean the difference is so goddamn subtle now... (in the code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I was able to reproduce the slowdown. This is just crazy... It is clearly caused by *glBindAttribLocation* being called on the "my_Position" attribute. Now I did some testing:

- 1 is default (as returned by *glGetAttribLocation*)
- if I set it to zero, theres no problem
- if I set it to 1, the rendering becomes slow
- if I set it to any larger number, it is slow again

Obviously I relink the program (check code). It is not a problem in the implementation, I tested it with "normal" values too.

Test program:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/dgg48g1fwgyc5h0/SLOWDOWN_REPRO.zip

How to repro:

- open with XCode
- open common/glext.h (don't be disturbed by the name)
- modify the GLDECLUSAGE_POSITION constant from 0 to 1
- compile and run => slow
- changing back to zero => good

Comment: THANK YOU! I have spent DAYS trying to find out why I was getting 15FPS for a  50K Tris model on a 2013 MacBook Pro. FPS jumped to infinity ( Needs a higher resolution timer :P )

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to get myself the same problem in the following circumstance under 
`OS X Mavericks:`

- Instanced rendering using array buffers to give each instance its own `modelToWorld` and `inverseNormal` matrices; attribute locations are being specified through layout rather than using `glGetAttribLocation`
- leaving one of these array buffers unused in the `shader`, where location is declared but the attribute isn't actually used for anything in the `glsl` code

In this case, a call to `glDrawElementsInstanced` takes up a LOT of CPU time *(under normal circumstances, this call uses nearly zero CPU even when drawing several thousand instances).*

You can tell that you're getting this specific problem if almost all of the CPU time used within `glDrawElementsInstanced` is spent in `gleDrawArraysOrElements_ExecCore`.  Making sure that all of the array buffers are actually referenced in your `shader` code fixes the CPU time back to (nearly) zero.

I suspect that this is one of the situations where leaving a variable out of your main() in `glsl` confuses the compiler in to deleting all reference to that variable, leaving you with a dangling reference to an attribute or uniform.

Comment: I suggest you report this to Apple too :) Apparently they didn't fix my problem either.

Comment: I have a similar problem with very simple shaders.
Thanks Deekey, though I am not using instanced rendering, having unused vector buffers does make the vector shader run on the CPU.

Comment: To further detail how bad it is, having a VAO with unused but bound variables will make the vertex shader run in software even if the unused variables are disabled.