# After updating to Mavericks, my OpenGL software runs the vertex shader on CPU

Tags: macos, opengl, osx-mavericks

I have a large C++ OpenGL software that was running with very high performance under Mountain Lion.
After updating to Mavericks and recompiling, the performance has dropped significantly.
By switching between Triangle strips and triangles as the type of object being rendered and seeing a drop in performance by a further factor 2 or 3, I am under the impression that the vertex shader must be the cause of the issue and given how simple it is, I suspect that it is running in software on the CPU rather than on the GPU.
How can I recover the performance I had under Mountain Lion? Are there some changes I need to do?

The source of my vertex shader is given below. It feeds a following geometry shader.

```
#version 410

uniform mat3 normalMatrix;
uniform mat4 modelMatrix;
uniform mat4 modelProjMatrix;
uniform vec3 color  = vec3(0.4,0.4, 0.4);

in vec3 vertex;
in vec3 normal;

out NodeData {
    vec3 normal, position;
    vec4 refColor;
} v;

void main()
{
    vec4 position = modelMatrix * vec4(vertex, 1.0);
    vec3 vertNormal = normal;
    v.normal = normalize(normalMatrix * vertNormal);
    v.position = position.xyz;

    v.refColor = vec4(color, 1.0);
    gl_Position = modelProjMatrix * vec4(vertex, 1.0);

}
```

For 180,000 triangles I can only get 3FPS when feeding as triangles and about 8 when fed as strips. The triangle are ordered according to Forsyth's optimization algorithm for post transform cache optimization.

Comment: You mentioned a geometry shader in this question, but have only shown the vertex shader. Geometry shaders are much more expensive than vertex shaders and I am willing to bet that that is where your actual bottleneck lies.

Comment: The reason I do not believe so is that whether I do a triangle strip or a set of triangles, the work of the geometry shader remains the same, while, assuming no post vertex transform caching, the vertex shader has three time as much work to do with triangles rather than with a strip. This factor three is almost exactly the performance difference I see between the two approaches. I will however try to shunt out the geometry shader to make sure.

Comment: The geometry shader effectively destroys the post-T&L cache while we are on this discussion. For every input primitive, it emits a new one complete with its own set of unshared vertices. GS are extremely inefficient, they are hard to parallelize at the hardware level because they can emit a variable number of vertices and they are hard to cache too. Also, the post-T&L cache is something used to speed up primitive assembly, and not so much vertex shading itself. The amount of work a vertex shader has to do does not change, merely the number of times it has to be redundantly invoked per-vertex.

Comment: I bypassed the geometry shader and the problem remains.

Comment: Andon, do you have a reference about the geometry shader destroying the post transform cache? I don't see why that would be the case. The geometry shader is being fed the triangles that would have to be formed and passed to the next step of the pipeline anyway. After that, the geometry shader does indeed create new versions of the triangles but the caching of the output of the vertex shader is still doable, so I don't see any reason why using a geometry shader would make the cache unusable.

Comment: Destroy probably was not the best choice of words. What I meant to say was that it kills many of the benefits of the T&L cache. Nicol Bolas wrote an [answer on the gamedev sister site](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/48432/why-does-this-geometry-shader-slow-down-my-program-so-much) that explains basically everything I was trying to tell you.

Comment: My problem seems related to the one reported here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16415037/opengl-core-profile-incredible-slowdown-on-os-x but I am still unable to fix it.

Comment: I did find the issue. It is described in the thread linked above. As soon as there is an unused Vector Buffer, the vertex shader runs on the CPU. Removing the unused buffers fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: Make sure all vector buffers that are added to the VAO are used in the vertex shader.