# Application built with Xcode 6/clang vs Xcode 4/gcc is much slower in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, clang, render

A large, complex OS X C++/OpenGL codebase (i.e. impossible to get a small fragment of code that illustrates the issue) was originally compiled with Xcode 4.6 and gcc.

After building using Xcode 6.1 and clang, the application runs much more slowly - typically 20-75% more slowly.

Using Instruments, I identified an area where the slowdown appears to happen - calls to glDrawRangeElements() in the render loop when built with clang take 100x more time than those with gcc.

Specifically, the call to glDrawRangeElements_IMM_Exec() takes all the time vs glDrawRangeElements_ACC_Exec() which takes about the same time.

I've rules out optimization issues between the two - both use -O3.  I've tried building with the same OpenGL framework from 10.7.

No idea where to start looking now - searching for those calls doesn't return anything useful.

Can anyone suggest some avenues to explore?

Comment: Sounds very odd. So the difference is with using the same frameworks on the same OS, and just changing compilers? Could it be something like uninitialized variables or memory stomping that causes these functions to be called with different arguments?

Comment: Yeah, maybe.  It's a huge codebase (~1,000,000 lines) so finding it will be hard.  Was hoping it was a missing or incorrect clang specific flag and easy to spot.Another thought was that it was related to one of the answers here http://stackoverflow.com/a/17115997/603983 but haven't been able to dig deep enough.